# why iam getting blank screen in this code

Tags: php, jquery

allmob.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() { 
        var result1 = []; 

        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() { 
            result1.push($(this).val()); 
        });

        var url = "mob1.php"
        if (result1.length > 0) { 
            //var fin = result1 ;
            $.post(url, { contval: result1 }, function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#result').html("nothing is checked");
        }
    });
});
```

If instead of passing `result1` I pass 1 like `$.post(url, { contval: 1 }, function(data)` I am getting the output and if I pass `result1` a blank screen comes.

mob.php:

```
 <?php 
     $contval = $_POST['contval'] ;

     if ($contval == "1")
     { 
         echo "1 is checked" ;
     }
   if($contval == "2")

     {
      echo "2 is selected" ;
     }
?>
```

**allmob.php**

```
   <?php 

  session_start();
    ?>
     <html>
     <head>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/allmob.css">
     <script type = "text/javascript="js/jquery1.11.3.js">                     </script>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src ="js/allmob.js"></script>
      </head>
     <body>
     <div class = "well">Add2Kart</div>
     <div class = "container">
     <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-lg-4">
  <h5>Price :</h5>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "price" value = "1">&#8377;1,000-&#8377;5,000</input><br>
     <input type = "checkbox" name = "price" value = "2">&#8377;5,000-&#8377;10,000</input><br>
         <input type = "checkbox" name = "price" value = "3">&#8377;10,000-&#8377;15,000</input><br>
         <input type = "checkbox" name = "price" value = "BETWEEN 15000 AND 25000">&#8377;15,000-&#8377;25,000</input><br>
         </div>


          <div class = "col-lg-8">
            <div id = "result" >

          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
      </html>
```

selected checkbox are handled by allmob.js and the value of selected checkbox are sent to mob.php so i want to do if value 1 checkbox get selected then in mob.php condition 1 print if bot 1 and 2 checkbox get selected both the conditions should print

Comment: In your first example, you're passing an array of values. In your second you're passing an int. Therefore the test for equality in your PHP is inherently flawed.

Comment: `$(':checkbox')` i doubt this.. can you add your html markup?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

`$_POST['contval']` is an array so you can't check it's value directly using "`==`"

```
<?php 
     $contval = $_POST['contval'] ;

     if (!empty($contval) &&  in_array("1", $contval)) 
     { 

         echo "1 is checked" ;
     }
?>
```